# Convert JavaScript array based on key value pairs from a JSON file.

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create a system to flag inappropriate comments for my app.

I have a system to convert the whole comment into an array of strings, however I would like to create a JavaScript function to convert all of these array items to a number value based on key value pairs from JSON. If a key is not found that matches the word it should be replaced by a 0.

All values in the final array will be added together to get a comment score.

Here is an example starting array:

```
["Bad", "reallyBad", "Good", "Neutral", "Good"]
```

I would like to compare this to a JSON key: value object such as:

```
{
    "reallyBad": -10,
    "Bad": -5,
    "Good": 5,
    "reallyGood": 10
}
```

Based on the key value pairs the new array should be this:

```
[-5, -10, 5, 0, 5]
```

Does anyone know a good place to start when converting strings based on a key: value pair?

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Just use `Array#map`: `wordArray.map(word => myWordObject[word])`

Comment: Javascript has numerous aways to iterate over array elements. Any of them should be easy to use for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.map()` on an array to perform a function on each item in the array and return something for that.  So, take each string in your array and use that as the key to get the value from your ratings object.

```js
const array = ["Bad", "reallyBad", "Good", "Neutral", "Good"];


const ratings = {
    "reallyBad": -10,
    "Bad": -5,
    "Good": 5,
    "reallyGood": 10
};

const ratingsArray = array.map(item => ratings[item] || 0);

console.log(ratingsArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just map the values of the object, or take a default value for `Neutral`.

```js
var array = ["Bad", "reallyBad", "Good", "Neutral", "Good"],
    weights = { reallyBad: -10, Bad: -5, Good: 5, reallyGood: 10 },
    result = array.map(w => weights[w] || 0);
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use  `Array.map()`

Try the following:

```js
var arr = ["Bad", "reallyBad", "Good", "Neutral", "Good"];
var obj = {
    "reallyBad": -10,
    "Bad": -5,
    "Good": 5,
    "reallyGood": 10
};

var result= arr.map((a)=> obj[a] || 0);

console.log(result);
```